# BCH Encoder/Decoder c Library

Tags: error-handling, error-correction

I was searching for BCH ECC library implemented in c without positive results. Do you know of any re-usable implementation?

Best regards,
Peter

Answer (score 1):

Dude there is a bch library in linux/lib (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/lib/bch.c)

The source code is given in the above url.
I am not sure how to use the library api in the user program.

I am guessing you need to compile and link the bch code into some shared object and then write your user C source.

while compiling link to the above compiled shared object.

gcc -c yourfile.c -l bch.so -o yourfile

Answer (score 1):

Link to a demo program with Berlekamp Massey decoder. Note that the large local arrays and matrices should be made static to avoid stack overflow issues. There's a list of generator polynomials chosen based on degree, which you might want to change to be user specified, or just change the code.

http://read.pudn.com/downloads181/sourcecode/app/842529/bch/bch_bm.c__.htm